# Non-parametric test for two sample quantiles

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, quantiles

I would like to know if there is a non-parametric test on quantiles.

EDIT: My focus is on continuous distributions (e.g. Weibull distribution).

In a general setting we define quantiles as $Q_X(p) = inf \{x \in \mathbf{R}: p \leq P(X\leq x)\}$. I would like to test $H_0: Q_X(p) = Q_Y(p)$ vs. $H_a: Q_X(p) \neq Q_Y(p)$ for some $p \in (0,1)$.

Comment: It is difficult to test the hypothesis of equality of quantiles when you make *no* assumptions about the distributions.  When you assume they are *continuous,* though, good tests can be devised (and this is still a non-parametric setting).  Your definition of quantile suggest you are considering the fully general case, but is that really true?

Comment: @whuber Yes, the distribution I have in mind is continuous. I'll make sure to add that to my question. The quantiles of my samples are estimated using a Weibull distribution.

Comment: If you're assuming a Weibull distribution, why do you want to go nonparametric?

Comment: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/book/export/html/835 I think this might be helpful but not enough.

Comment: @Dave Non-parametric methods have less assumptions, that's the reason I'm interested in such test. Weibull distribution was an example that came to me for a continuous variable, I am interested if there is a test when the distribution is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, one approach to compare quantiles is Mood's median test, which is a nonparametric approach that counts the observations in each group that are greater than the global median, those less-than or equal to the global median, and applying a chi-square test of association.  This approach is essentially nonparametric in that it simply counts the number of observations in each category.  It is best if the sampled population is continuous in nature; practically speaking if many observations are tied to the global median, the test can get funky.  It would be easy to modify this test to apply to any quantile.